# See Repositories where I am Collaborator

Tags: github

I am a collaborator on a private repo, but it doesn't show up under my repositories.  I also cannot see it on the other user's repository listing because it is private. I have confirmed that I am able to push/pull to the repo.  Is there a way to access this repository using Github without typing in the full URL ?

Comment: As of 2022/09/30, none of the answers below really provide the information the Question is asking for.  In some of them, you can see some, but they are not annotated any differently from other repos you've commented on etc.
Wonder how long this will take to fix?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can see the repositories where you're a collaborator. To do this, head to the **Repositories** section of your account's settings (https://github.com/settings/repositories).

There should be a **Leave** action button aside each repository you're a collaborator on.

Comment: Hmm.. 
Which genius came up with the idea of putting it in the settings page?

Comment: Under this section you won't see repositories where you are *collaborator* but repositories where you have access. You become collaborator when your PR gets merged, but it doesn't make you project's member (and won't be listed on mentioned view). @KLicheR's tip was valid for this particular situation because Xst asked about private repo (for which access must be granted and it will be listed in the settings), but in that case asked question's title should be different ;-)

Comment: As of today, it also works to see owned repositories with collaborators.

Comment: This doesn't show private repos.

Comment: I think "settings" nowadays means everything that is not your repo

Comment: Looks like they are not using the same API to get the repository list :D

Answer (score 64):

Even though it won't show up in YOUR repositories, it should appear on your github dashboard (click the github logo), on the bottom right.  There should be a list that has buttons at the top to filter all, public, and private repos.  Try clicking the private button and it should be there.

> Note that if you have opted in to the new dashboard, the above doesn't apply, but you can see the repositories (owner and collaborator) on the left..

Comment: To clarify: this only holds true for "private" repositories. On that dashboard you don't see the public repositories from other organizations where you are a collaborator.

Comment: @Pacerier afaics under "repositories you contribute to" on that dashboard or on your profile page > repositories tab https://github.com/USERNAME?tab=repositories

Comment: @AlexanderKlimetschek, And for another user?

Comment: This does not seem to work on the current (new) github dashboard. @klicher's answer works on the current github.

Comment: @NH. Sorry, I'm opted in for the new beta dashboard. I thought it was deployed for everyone now. With the beta dashboard I'm unable to follow your steps.

Comment: @NH I guess it's nice to mention it. But the left list on the beta dashboard is really weird. My list is a mix of a lot of repos and I can't really tell why they're in the list. I got a repo listed where I'm pretty sure my only interaction is that I've commented on an issue. When that list starts to grow it becomes almost useless. The dashboard is still beta though, so I guess this might change.

Answer (score 14):

A simpler place (as per today) to find private repositories you are collaborating on is to go to https://github.com/ (do not include your username, but make sure you are already logged in). On the left hand side, you can find a search interface or click "show more" to see them all.
It's weird that as per today, if you try to do this from the Repositories you won't find them.

Comment: This is essentially the same as @NH. answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12845759/1429390