# How to find repo as Github collaborator?

Tags: github

My friend added me as a collaborator to one of his repositories on github, but I don't see the repo anywhere in my list. Where can I find it besides on my friend's profile?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The repo is a public one, NOT private.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See Repositories where I am Collaborator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453358/see-repositories-where-i-am-collaborator)

Answer (score 0):

In the settings, repositories section, you can see it