# What is the difference between a pull request by a collaborator and contributor in GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request, code-collaborator

what is the difference between a pull request by a collaborator and contributor in GitHub? I don't find any special privileges for collaborators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one special privilege a collaborator has over a contributor is... that they (the collaborator) can push *directly* to *your* repository (since you have [added them as "collaborator"](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)).

They can push their own branch and do a pull request from withi your repo, between their branch and master.

As opposed to a contributor, [who has to fork your repository first](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), and make a pull request from their own fork/branch to your repo/master.

Comment: So, a collaborator no need to fork the repository to work on that project? Then where shall we find the repositories in which we are collaborators?

Comment: @anna Yes, a collaborator does not need to fork (but still can if they want to). For your second question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429691/6309, and, if you are logged in to GitHub: https://github.com/settings/repositories

Answer (score 4):

#### Difference between a **Contributor**, **Collaborator**, **Author**, **Owner**

- **Contributor:** A contributor is someone from the outside not on the core development team of the project that wants to contribute some changes to a project.
- **Collaborator:** A collaborator is someone on the core development team of the project and has `commit-access` to the main repository of the project.
- **Author:** The person/s or organization that created the project
- **Owner:** The person/s who has administrative ownership over the organization or repository (not always the same as the original author)
- **Maintainers:** Contributors who are responsible for driving the vision and managing the organizational aspects of the project. (They may also be authors or owners of the project.)
- **Community Members:** People who use the project. They might be active in conversations or express their opinion on the project’s direction.

Reference:

[GitHub Guide](https://opensource.guide/how-to-contribute/#anatomy-of-an-open-source-project) and [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/).