# Cannot see my collaboration projects in my Github profile

Tags: github, collaboration

Me and my friend are working on a project. He created the initial project repository and added me as a collaborator. His github: https://github.com/Aidanas93 , My github: https://github.com/MantasVa .
As you can see we are both working on this project together:  https://github.com/Aidanas93/PhysicalTherapyWebApplication

But I can not see this repository in my github profile. I dont want my github repository to appear empty for my future employeer. The problem is that I want to apply for  internships. If I will send my profile, It will seem as an empty one. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to push your commits to your main branch. In that way, you will be able to pin the repo you collaborated to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your friends role? 
https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization

Comment: There is no option to select collaborator role, only to remove him.

Comment: Here's what I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453358/see-repositories-where-i-am-collaborator

Comment: thanks for your help, but our problem is with public repository. We cannot see projects that we are colllaborators on.